# AWS EC2 - nginx - Proxypass with aws public DNS name

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services

I want to proxy my public dns name `ec2-someiphere.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` to `https://api.example.com` I have the following in my nginx.conf:

```
    server {
            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80;
            server_name api.example.com ec2-someiphere.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 1.1.1.1;
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    server {
            listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
            listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
            server_name api.example.com;
            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            }
            ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/fullchain.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/privkey.pem;
            ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
            ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;
            ssl_session_timeout 1h;
            add_header Strict-Transport-Security “max-age=15768000” always;
    }
```

When I start nginx it produces an error. (It doesn't like the `ec2-someiphere.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`) If I don't have `ec2-someiphere.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` in there, it won't redirect when someone hits that and shows the default nginx page instead of redirecting. Is there anyway around this??

EDIT: The error I get when using the long DNS name is:

```
-- Unit nginx.service has begun starting up.
Sep 16 03:32:55 ip-172-31-48-100 nginx[7106]: nginx: [emerg] could not 
build server_names_hash, you should increase 
server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64
Sep 16 03:32:55 ip-172-31-48-100 nginx[7106]: nginx: configuration 
file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I assume this is because the DNS name is too long??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question. Turns out there is a max size to the server name, but it is editable.

By putting: `server_names_hash_bucket_size 128` at the http level it will stop the error. Hopefully this is not a problem for performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the hostnames in the first server block with `_`, it will become the default block for all port 80 hits and you already have the redirect URL set up to be dynamic.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

If that's not suitable, please post the error message verbatim.

Comment: Hi Gary, Thanks for the reply. I have already tried that. It makes all requests then redirect to the nginx default site instead of proxying the request. I get the error: -- Unit nginx.service has begun starting up.
Sep 16 03:32:55 ip-172-31-48-100 nginx[7106]: nginx: [emerg] could not build server_names_hash, you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64
Sep 16 03:32:55 ip-172-31-48-100 nginx[7106]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed. I assume this is because the server name is too long?